# Find path of BLAS or MKL that is linked to numpy

Tags: python, numpy, blas, intel-mkl

I want to check the path of BLAS or MKL which is linked to the `numpy`.

The system is already built by the others and I don't have root account.

Is there any way to find the path in python command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following command

```
np.__config__.show()
```

show_config command shows the libraries in the system on which numpy was built.

[Documentation link](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.show_config.html)

Thanks